# Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects ask system reboot on reinstall

Tags: visual-studio-2017, reinstall, service-installer

I have service project and Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects to install it. If I start uninstall from "Add or remove project", then install new version - All Ok. If I start installation from Visual Studio - All Ok

But if Start installation using msi file from explorer. Installer ask me to reboot system. 
How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using REBOOT=ReallySuppress at the end of your installation command.